# Make a binary to always run in a cgroup

Tags: memory, selinux, cgroups, apparmor

I want to make sure a binary located at certain path is always run as part of a certain cgroup. Everything I found so far involves running the binary through some special command *(e.g. with `systemd-run` or with `cgexec`)*. That's not quite what I want because finding all possible ways a binary could be invoked *(through terminal, through a DE launch-panel, through an autostart…)* and trying to modify them would be a daunting task.

I assume I need to somehow combine AppArmor or SELinux with cgroups, but I couldn't find any explanation on how to do that.

---

Background: on my work laptop I sometimes suffer from swap-storms. I ventured to try to tune my system. Following ["in defence of swap"](https://chrisdown.name/2018/01/02/in-defence-of-swap.html) blog-post I did some experimentation, and figured that `vm.swappiness = 100` is better than the lower `vm.swappiness = 10`, even on HDD, at least with zswap and for my workflow. After using that for a while I noticed a weird thing: Skype process, which I only use once in the morning and which just idles in the background the rest of the time, managed to get through two swap-storms with 0 *(zero!)* kbytes in SWAP. Only on 3rd swap-storm Skype has gotten a tiny bit *(compared to other processes of a similar PSS)* on each of its 6 processes into SWAP. This is a surprising behavior, and is something I dislike. I want Skype to be one of the first victims to the reclamation, because 97% of its runtime it does nothing besides just "being online".

At the same time, I also figured I might want to reduce possibility of reclamation for some other essential processes, such as i3 and Plasma.

cgroups provides various `memory` hooks for that, such as `memory.low` mentioned in the article. So I want to make use of that to tune various processes in my system. But I want to make sure it works disregarding whether a binary was run from a terminal, or through `rofi`, or some other way.

As a hack, I could replace the binaries I'm interested in with a wrapper-script that runs the original executable through `systemd-run`. But it would get overwritten on the next update; and it is clearly a hack, so, meh.

Answer (score 1):

Both AppArmor and SELinux are LSM modules. They are not aware of cgroups. You can't use them for this purpose.

Using wrapper approach is imho the best option.

You can place the wrapper in `~/bin` directory and put this directory at first place in your `PATH` environment variable. Then in the wrapper you need to use full file path of the binary, so that you will avoid endless loop. This way, all tools which use relative binary name and follow `PATH` will execute the wrapper. But it also means that you may need to tweak `.desktop` files so that it uses the wrapper, as these usually uses a full file path of executable.

If you really want to avoid wrapper, you will have to write a script which monitors running processes and moves the ones which matches your criteria to it's targe cgroups. I consider that a more hackish compared to the wrapper approach.